# RegionPlot: Generate region specification {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5} etc. from a list?

Tags: plotting, regions, coding-style

A simple working example of `RegionPlot3D`is

```
klist = {k1, k2, k3};
RegionPlot3D[
 Times @@ klist < 1, {k1, -5, 5}, {k2, -5, 5}, {k3, -5, 5}]
```

However, I would like to not explicitly write out  `{k1, -5, 5}`etc. by hand, but rather get the variables from a list, e.g. `{klist[[1]], -5, 5}`. I am finding this more difficult than expected (Mathematica 11.0.1 for Windows 64-bit). For instance, this fails:

```
RegionPlot3D[Times @@ klist < 1, 
{klist[[1]], -5, 5}, {klist[[2]], -5, 5}, {klist[[3]], -5, 5}]

(* RegionPlot3D::write: Tag Part in klist[[1]] is Protected. *)
```

Plotting over a `Cuboid[]` does not work either:

```
RegionPlot3D[Times @@ klist < 1, 
klist \[Element] Cuboid[{-5, -5, -5}, {5, 5, 5}]] 

(* RegionPlot3D::pllim: Range specification klist\[Element]Cuboid[{-5,-5,-5},{5,5,5}] 
    is not of the form {x, xmin, xmax}. *)
```

The closest I got to my goal is with this rather convoluted solution:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 ImplicitRegion[(Times @@ klist < 1) && And @@ Thread[-5 < klist < 5],
   Evaluate@klist]]
```

[image]

I can't help but wonder if there is an easier way I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
RegionPlot3D @@ Join[{Times @@ klist < 1}, Evaluate@{#, -5, 5} & /@ klist]
```

Comment: Thank you! Evaluation was the key I was missing. Perfect.